# What are some free chess software for showing the best moves in the final output analysis?

Tags: analysis, software

I appreciate any free chess software that can be used for analyzing chess games. However, some of them are difficult to use, showing a large number of lines with many moves which are not displayed in the chessboard. As a result, someone has to be comfortable with reading chess notation to understand them. Another issue is that many chess programs show only the best line for each move in the final analysis output. It might be useful to also know the second or third best move for example.

I was wondering: how many **free** chess programs are there:

1. showing the best moves/lines (from best to worst) **and** allowing
   the user to navigate through them visually on the board?
2. rating each move (something like excellent/good/mistake/blunder)?
3. export an analysis concentrating all the above information?

[Lucas chess](https://lucaschess.pythonanywhere.com/) is the only free chess software that I know satisfying all the above.

[Scid](http://scid.sourceforge.net/) is also close to that, but I think that it displays only the best line for each move in the final output (if this isn't the case, please describe how someone can see more than one line for each move in the final analysis using scid).

Is there any other free chess program doing all that?

Answer (score 2):

You can download Stockfish for free. It has a great UI. You can also use the engine with scripting languages such as python which we do for our app [Chess Puzzle Blitz](https://www.chesspuzzleblitz.com).

Stockfish: [https://stockfishchess.org/](https://stockfishchess.org)

Both Lichess and Chess.com have analysis tools (you can load a PGN or FEN, or manually set a board).

[Chess.com](https://www.chess.com/analysis): https://www.chess.com/analysis
[Lichess.org](https://lichess.org/analysis): https://lichess.org/analysis